# Print rows that contain values in vector/column in R

Tags: r, filter

I have some data looking like this:

```
1. matrix

  a b c d e

f 4 5 6 7 8

g 1 2 3 4 5

h 3 2 1 6 7

2. column/vector

v <- c(5,4,8,6,0)
```

How can I print all the rows that contain the data in vector?

I've seen there's a function called filter that could work, or maybe lapply / grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` with `if_any`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . %in% v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `base R` (assuming it is a `matrix`)

```
m1[rowSums(`dim<-`(m1 %in% v, dim(m1))) > 0,]
```